# Can't resolve 'os' , webpack 5

Tags: reactjs

So I was making a webpack5 application, as I added web3, I faced this issue

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 23:9-22
```

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\Arex\Desktop\webpack5-react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
- install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change/70560145#70560145

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem. It's because Webpack 5 doesn't include polyfills for node.js anymore.

### A simple solution:

Add this plugin https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
}
```

This will add those node.js polyfills you're probably missing.

Answer (score 4):

As of Dec 2022, the proper solution appears to be adding this to the top of your `webpack.config.js`:

`target: "node"`

Credit to: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-979735420

Comment: Tried this, but then I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at require chunk loading:1:1
    at require chunk loading:478:1
    at startup:5:1`

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

Install os-browserify and react-app-rewired

```sh
npm install os-browserify react-app-rewired
```

### Step 2

In your project root, create `config-overrides.js` file.

In this file, put this.

```js
module.exports = function override (config, env) {
    console.log('override')
    let loaders = config.resolve
    loaders.fallback = {
        // existing configs...
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
   }
    
    return config
}
```

### Step 3

**important !**

Change `"start": react-scripts start` in your package.json to `"start": react-app-rewired start`

## Now, restart your project.

```sh
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

i just had to add

```json
        fallback: {
            os: false,
        },
```

to webpack config like the webpack error mentioned.

Comment: Where did you add?

Comment: root->resolve->fallback