# NFT React + web3.js importing .env issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

i am running a NFT Minter tutorial from this Github Repo:

https://github.com/alchemyplatform/nft-minter-tutorial/tree/main/nft-minter

I was able to backtrack to the issue when building on the minter-starter-files to the very top of the interact.js file.

```
'"require('dotenv').config();
const alchemyKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ALCHEMY_KEY;
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(alchemyKey); '"
```

I am importing the .env file in the /nft-minter/src/util/interact.js however I am met with the issue :

```
'"Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 24:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\dotenv\lib'


ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 26:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 71:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 46:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/helpers.js 11:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }







ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Wills\Documents\GitHub\nft-minter-tutorial\minter-starter-files\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }'"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I answered it here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change/70560145#70560145