# Getting this error while trying to build: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ethereum, web3js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }"

please advise

Comment: I solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `require('crypto')` (or maybe `import from 'crypto`) in your code.

`crypto` is a built-in Node.js extension and you are trying to build a browser project.

If that is what you need, as the webpack error message says, you should install a polyfill that implements `crypto` for the browser.