# "webpack 5 breaking change" after installing Jimp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, jimp

I am building a react app with react-dom v18 and react v18. I installed jimp, and got the following error. And I am not using webpack, but not sure where this error is coming from, downgrading react seems to help, but thats not ideal for me, so can any one help me?
I got 18 of these errors

````
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/[blurred path]/node_modules/@jimp/core/es'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false } ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change)